# Solve and plot an equation that is dependent on a transcendental equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am trying to plot a function that uses the values of a transcendental equation as its input values:

```
y = Tanh[(2 y + x)/2.5]
z = 2.5 * Log[2*Cosh[(2 y + x)/2.5]]
```

for $x = [-1.5, 1.5]$.

I am a relative newbie to *Mathematica*, so I am at a complete loss as to how to go about this. I have successfully plotted the transcendental equation itself using `ContourPlot`, and mathematically I know what to do - but I can't for the life of it figure out how to make *Mathematica* solve these two equations and plot the result.

I find the *Mathematica* notation to be somewhat cryptic, but I really love the results, so I want to get good at it. Can somebody help?

Comment: By the way, welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time [you will be able to do more on the site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges) (post graphics, edit things, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[x_] := y /. FindRoot[y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/2.5], {y, x}]

Plot[2.5 Log[2 Cosh[(2 f[x] + x)/2.5]], {x, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image: plot]

**1. Analyze**

```
g[x_, d_] := y /. FindRoot[y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/d], {y, x}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[g[x, d], {x, -1.5, 1.5},
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}],
 {{d, 2.5}, 1, 3}]
```

**2. Min/Max values**

This example gives an idea how to redefine `g`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{y, Tanh[(2 y + x)/d]}, {y, -2, 2}],
 {{d, 1.5}, 0, 3},
 {{x, 1}, -5, 5}]

g[x_, d_: 1.5] :=
 With[{x0 = If[x < 0, -1, 1]},
  y /. FindRoot[y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/d], {y, x0}]]

ListPlot[Table[{x, g[x]}, {x, -2, 2, .05}],
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot2]

Instead of `ContourPlot` you can also solve first equation for `x(y)` as @Alexei pointed out.

```
With[{d = 1.5},
 Plot[d (ArcTanh[y] - 2 y), {y, -2, 2},
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: plot3]

**3. Functions z(x,y) and y'(x)**

Note that you can simplify your `z` with how `y` is defined.

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, -2.5 Log[2 Cosh[ArcTanh[g[x, 2]]]]},
  {x, -2, 2, .05}], Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot4]

Regarding derivative, calculate that again for what you've commented is not true. Check:

```
Solve[y'[x] == D[Tanh[(2 y[x] + x)/d], x], y'[x]]
```

So you can define it like this:

```
dy[x_, d_: 1.5] :=
 With[{y = g[x, d]},
  Divide[
   Sech[(2 y + x)/d]^2,
   d - 2 Sech[(2 y + x)/d]^2]]

ListPlot[Table[{x, dy[x]}, {x, -2, 2, .05}]]
```

[image: plot5]

Because of the pole I can't force `Joined -> True`. I could do that if I offset *x*'s a little in the last `Table` (e.g. `-2 - .1`). I can also do this:

```
Module[{dx = .05, left},
 left = Table[{x, dy[x, 2]}, {x, -2, -dx, dx}];
 Graphics[{
   Line[left],
   Line[left /. {x_, y_} :> {-x, y}]},
  Axes -> True]]
```

[image: plot6]

Comment: Ditto here - that was one quick reply! :) Your solution seems simpler, but can I also use this method for the function described above (1.5 rather than 2.5 in the denominator):

y = Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5]

where I want to use the minimum values of y for [-∞;0] and maximum values for [0;∞] - because this function has (is supposed to have) a jump-continuity at 0?

Comment: @nielsen Right, something happens as denominator drops below 2. You can start analyzing that with `Manipulate` example above.

Comment: @nielsen Sort of forking occurs. Suddenly more solutions for y are possible depending on x.

Comment: Yes, precisely - the function has several possible solutions for each x in the vicinity of 0. But I know that mathematically I only need the minimum values of y for [-∞;0] and maximum values for [0;∞] - so how do I pick just those for y = Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5]? Because then the function becomes one-to-one again (except of course in zero), so Mathematica shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: @nielsen Which y will you use with z, min or max? Both perhaps and calculating zmin and zmax, yes?

Comment: I tried your widget - but the widget incorrectly introduces noise to the range close to zero. I can't post images, but y = Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5] is a smooth s-curve - where the s-bit is shaped like an actual s - however, I only need the minimum values of y for x ∈ [-∞;0] and maximum values of y for x ∈ [0;∞] (i.e. with a jump discontinuity at zero). This displays the full curve correctly: ContourPlot[{y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}, PlotPoints -> 100]

Comment: @nielsen Sort of noise, I see. I think those are solutions of `FindRoot` converging uncontrollably and to undesired roots. I added some code. Have you already moved on from this problem?

Comment: No, I haven't - your help is very much appreciated! :) I posted a seperate question as to how to choose min/max values of a transcendental function (for d = 1.5) - however, I am still working with this problem to get the results, that the official solution says should come out of these equations.

Comment: In particular, the transcendental equation y == Tanh[2y + x/d] for d = 2, clearly becomes vertical in x = 0 - however, when I plug y == Tanh[2y + x/2] into z == -2*Log[2*Cosh[(2 y + x)/2]], I do not get an asymptote in x = 0 as I would expect (the official solution also states this), but rather a peak at y = -1.6 - so what am I doing wrong? Is this a precision issue with Mathematica and asymptotes, am I not plugging y == Tanh[(2y + x)/2] in correctly or have I just missed something on the mathematical side? (P.S. I had by accident lost a minus in front of z along the way)

Comment: Likewise for the derivative of y == Tanh[2y + x/2], namely y' = dy/dx = (1/2)*Sech[(2y + x)/2]^2, I should also and in particular get an asymptote in x = 0 - but I just don't, instead I get a peak at y = 0.5. For both z and dy/dx I get qualitatively the right graphs, so I am fairly certain I am doing this right - but the asymptotes I would expect are missing?

Comment: @nielsen I think you should think it over again...I added few results ("chapter 3").

Comment: You are right - I have indeed done the derivative wrong. Thank you for that. And wowsa, now I have to sit down and study the syntax of the solution you have suggest closer - but at least that does confirm, that what I've been trying to do in Mathematica isn't exactly trivial - and I *am* a beginner at this. Thank you very much for your time - and I might still have questions, if I may?

Comment: @nielsen Hey, no problem, and sure, feel free to pose questions. You might want to join chat though (top menu), there is a chat room ["Discussion between BoLe and Aky"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8986/discussion-between-bole-and-aky), shall we converse there? Messages are stored and notifications done.

Comment: Thank you and yes, let's - I've posted a couple of simpler questions (though not for me) in the chat, on how to plot y as a function of d as well. :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
nielsensFunction[x_?InexactNumberQ] :=
   \[FormalY] /. First @ FindRoot[\[FormalY] - Tanh[2 (2 \[FormalY] + x)/5],
                                  {\[FormalY], Tanh[x]}, WorkingPrecision -> Precision[x]]
```

I used a formal symbol as a temporary variable within `FindRoot[]` for safety, since they are guaranteed to never have any values assigned to them. Looking at `ContourPlot[y == Tanh[2 (2 y + x)/5], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -1, 1}]`, the curve looked not too different from `Tanh[x]`, so I elected to use `Tanh[x]` as a seed for `FindRoot[]`.

Having done this, we can now do the following:

```
Plot[{nielsensFunction[x], 5 Log[2 Cosh[2 (2 nielsensFunction[x] + x)/5]]/2},
     {x, -3/2, 3/2}]
```

[image: some plots]

Comment: Holy smokes, that was fast - I am duly impressed! :D Can I just ask - what if I instead want to use this function (1.5 rather than 2.5 in the denominator):

y = Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5]

where I want to use the minimum values of y for [-∞;0] and maximum values for [0;∞] - because this function has (is supposed to have) a jump-continuity at 0?

Comment: Right, `Tanh[x]`, or just `x`, is a better seed.

Comment: @BoLe, not sure about using `x`, as it doesn't have the same qualitative behavior...

Comment: @nielsen, that requires some more work; maybe use calculus to find the range where the function is no longer one-to-one, and then build approximants appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

One very simple way without actually solving something is to note that form the first equation one can express x as

```
-2. y + 2.5 ArcTanh[y]
```

and that this can be substituted into the second equation, which then only depends upon y. This enables one to use the variable y as a parameter and apply the parametric plot. By playing with its limits one easily finds that the limits for the variable y are from approximately -0.855 to approximately +0.855. 
Evaluate this:

```
     ParametricPlot[{-2. y + 2.5 ArcTanh[y], 
  2.5*Log[2*Cosh[ArcTanh[y]]]}, {y, -0.855, 0.855}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "z"}]
```

[image: This I see on the screen after evaluation]

Comment: Good point - I hadn't even noticed that!