# Choosing min/max values of transcendental equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

With help from here, I have succeeded in plotting the equation `z = -a Log[2 Cosh[(2 f[x] + x)/a]]`, with `f[x]` being defined by the transcendental equation `f[x] = Tanh[(2 f[x] + x)/a`. However, for `a < 2` each `x` in the vicinity of `0` has up to three possible values of `y` as a soultion.

```
f[x_] := y /. FindRoot[y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5], {y, 0}]
p1 = Plot[-1.5 Log[2 Cosh[(2 f[x] + x)/1.5]], {x, -1.5, 1.5}];
Show[p1,  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-3.1, -0.9}},  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

I know that `y = Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5]` is supposed to have a jump-discontinuity for `x = 0`, and be one-to-one everywhere else.

So, how do I make *Mathematica* use only the **minimum** values of

```
  y = Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5] for x ∈ [-∞, 0]
```

and **maximum** values of

```
  y = Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5] for x ∈ [0, ∞]
```

when I plot

```
z = -1.5 Log[2 Cosh[(2 y + x)/1.5]]
```

?

Comment: This was my original question:
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25846/solve-and-plot-an-equation-that-is-dependent-on-a-transcendental-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
f[x_] := y /. Which[x <= 0, FindRoot[y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5], {y, -5}], x > 0,FindRoot[y == Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5], {y, 5}]]
p1 = Plot[-1.5 Log[2 Cosh[(2 f[x] + x)/1.5]], {x, -1.5, 1.5}];
Show[p1, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-3.1, -0.9}},AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

It gives this:

[image: f(x)]

Which is not a jump discontinuity, but a discontinuity in its derivative.

Comment: Thank you very much - that was exactly what I was looking for! :) And no, that is not a jump discontinuity - it is y = Tanh[(2 y + x)/1.5] that has a jump discontinuity in x = 0.